# bcdiv equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, equivalent

Is there a "simple" js version of php's bcdiv? Because this isn't working as expected:

`var x = 11,
y = Math.round(x / 7) + " + " + x % 7)`

The expected result is 1 + 4, while the result i get is 2 + 4 (because 11 / 7 = 1,5 which becomes 2 after rounding).

Using `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` also gives a wrong result.

What i try is to calculate the difference between two dates in weeks and days. Using bcdiv in php works fine, i just cant find a proper way in JS.

What i want: `16.04.2011 to 15.12.2013 = 139 Weeks, 1 Day`

What i get: `16.04.2011 to 15.12.2013 = 137 Weeks, 1 Day`

Comment: "_Using `Math.floor` also gives a wrong result._" When?

Comment: Why would you be using `bcdiv` for such small numbers anyway?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Dunno, why that happened before. Now, it works...

Comment: JS doesn't have anything like any of the BC Math functions. Its numbers are all IEEE floating point, not arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - That was just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parseInt` instead of `Math.round` to truncate the decimal part, like this

```
var x = 11, y = parseInt(x / 7) + " + " + x % 7;
console.log(y)
```

**Output**

```
1 + 4
```

Comment: How is that any different from `Math.floor`, which OP stated gives the wrong result (for some reason)?

Comment: Dont ask me, but now it worked with `Math.floor`... But ty for the alternative.